# Can I use any 5 volt 2 ampere (that is, 10 W) charging adapter to charge my iPad 2018?

Tags: ipad, battery, charging, power, android

My iPad's charging adapter has malfunctioned. The lightning to USB cable is fine. My place is likely to be under a Covid19 lock down for at least two more weeks, so I cannot get a replacement soon.

Can I meanwhile use an android charging adapter to charge my iPad?

I checked the specs. The apple adapter has 5.1 V X 2.1 Amp output (10 W). My Android (Motorola) adapter is 5 V X 1.6 A (8 W) output. I have another android adapter (Vivo) with 5 V X 1 A output (5 W).

I tried the android adapters briefly. They are working with the iPad.

I connected the iPad to my windows PC. There it is charging very slowly (~6% per hour).

There is one complication with the Motorola adapter. It also has 2 turbo charging modes- 9 V X 1.6 A (~15 W) and 12 V X 1.2 A (~14.5 W). But these turbo charging modes only work for a supported device, otherwise the output is simply the 5 V X 1.6 A one.

But, to play it safe, should I use the other adapter with a single 5 W output?

Should I even try these android adapters?

I do feel that what really matters is the voltage and the current of the supply. Still, I do not want to wreck my iPad, and that too in the middle of a lock down.

If the charging is fast enough, do I really need to get the apple charging adapter later?

Comment: Also dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303399/119271; https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275566/119271

Comment: USB Charging is a standard.  If it has a USB-A port, it will deliver 5V.  If it has a USB-C port, it will negotiate.  The amperage really doesn't matter.  If it's too little it will charge slowly, if it's more, it will only supply what the iPad asks for.  So, you can use any USB charger with your iPad.

Comment: There might be  problem if the tension has an alternative component. If I were you I would try.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE I don't know what tension you are referring to in this context.

Comment: The supply tension.  This can be checked with an oscilloscope.